# How to show icon is hoverable with cursor

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I have a fontawesome icon with an onclick to act as a button. Everything works properly, but when I hover over the icon, my mouse doesn't change from a pointer into the finger.

How can I achieve this behavior?

This is the simple icon implementation:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
    className='text-white'
    icon={faChevron}
    onClick={this.next}
    size='lg'
/>
```

Comment: use cursor: pointer; attribute

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use CSS to change the mouse cursor like this:

```
.text-white {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

There are many other variants, see this MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.text-white:hover {
cursor:pointer
}
```